# g++ inconsistencies in regards to zero literals

Tags: c++, g++, clang++

As in title, g++ compiler seems to be inconsistent when it comes to accepting  zero literal assignment and I'd like to ask professionals what is the reason.
With preC++11 standard this code (apart from nullptr keyword) is valid. clang seems to be at least a lot better. Is it a persistent bug that is supposed to fixed? Thanks for explanation.

```
#include <cstddef>

struct A{
  int var;
  int A::* a;
};

int main(){
  A a;
  a.a = &A::var;    // Obviously compiles.
  a.a = nullptr; 
  a.a = NULL;       // Should be the same as nullptr as for C++11+
  a.a = 0;          // Conversion from integer zero literal to pointer is allowed
  a.a = (int)0;     // This is not allowed? I guess one step of indirection ruins exception rule from line above
  a.a = (int)'\0';  // Compiles on g++, what?
  a.a = (char)0;    // Doesn't compile.
  a.a = (char)'\0'; // Doesn't compile
  // All of this compiles on g++.
  a.a = (short)0;
  a.a = (long)0;
  a.a = (long long)0;
  a.a = (long long)0x0;
  a.a = (long long)0b0;
}
```

Results:

```
g++ (GCC) 8.2.1 20181127 // All stds as flags C++11+
/tmp/test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/tmp/test.cpp:14:14: error: cannot convert ‘int’ to ‘int A::*’ in assignment
   a.a = (int)0; // This is not allowed? I guess one step of indirection ruins exception rule from line above
              ^
/tmp/test.cpp:16:15: error: cannot convert ‘char’ to ‘int A::*’ in assignment
   a.a = (char)0; // Doesn't compile.
               ^
/tmp/test.cpp:17:15: error: cannot convert ‘char’ to ‘int A::*’ in assignment
   a.a = (char)'\0'; // Doesn't compile
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
g++ (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516 // All stds as flags C++11+
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:14:14: error: cannot convert ‘int’ to ‘int A::*’ in assignment
   a.a = (int)0; // This is not allowed? I guess one step of indirection ruins exception rule from line above
              ^
test.cpp:17:15: error: cannot convert ‘char’ to ‘int A::*’ in assignment
   a.a = (char)'\0'; // Doesn't compile
               ^~~~              ^~~~
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
clang version 7.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_701/final) // All stds as flags C++11+ 
Debian clang version 3.5.0-10 (tags/RELEASE_350/final) (based on LLVM 3.5.0) // All stds as flags C++11+ 
/tmp/test.cpp:14:9: error: assigning to 'int A::*' from incompatible type 'int'
  a.a = (int)0; // This is not allowed? I guess one step of indirection ruins exception rule from line above
        ^~~~~~
/tmp/test.cpp:15:8: error: assigning to 'int A::*' from incompatible type 'int'
        a.a = (int)'\0'; // Compiles, what?
              ^~~~~~~~~
/tmp/test.cpp:16:9: error: assigning to 'int A::*' from incompatible type 'char'
  a.a = (char)0; // Doesn't compile.
        ^~~~~~~
/tmp/test.cpp:17:9: error: assigning to 'int A::*' from incompatible type 'char'
  a.a = (char)'\0'; // Doesn't compile
        ^~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/test.cpp:19:9: error: assigning to 'int A::*' from incompatible type 'short'
  a.a = (short)0;
        ^~~~~~~~
/tmp/test.cpp:20:8: error: assigning to 'int A::*' from incompatible type 'long'
        a.a = (long)0;
              ^~~~~~~
/tmp/test.cpp:21:8: error: assigning to 'int A::*' from incompatible type 'long long'
        a.a = (long long)0;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/test.cpp:22:8: error: assigning to 'int A::*' from incompatible type 'long long'
        a.a = (long long)0x0;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/test.cpp:23:8: error: assigning to 'int A::*' from incompatible type 'long long'
        a.a = (long long)0b0;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
9 errors generated.
```

Comment: *g++ compiler seems to be inconsistent* really ? Is more simple, the compiler does what it has to do to follow the specifications of C++. A good advice, when you think the compiler is wrong change your mind and think *you* are wrong

Comment: "Literal" refers to the language syntax piece, a type of single preprocessor token, and not to the meaning of an expression.  So yes, a cast expression is never a literal, and is therefore not a null pointer constant (unless it has type `std::nullptr_t`), just like `1-1` is not a null pointer constant.

Comment: @aschepler It is not so obvious, especially that 1-1 was valid before C++11 and then it was standarised to be illegal.

Comment: Well, yes, I didn't say it was obvious. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After [DR 903](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#903), integral constant expressions that are not integral literals are not considered as null pointer constants any more, so all lines after `a.a = (int)0;` (included) are invalid. GCC wrongly accepts some of them and there are already some bug reports ([59704](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59704), [77712](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77712)) related to this issue.